# How do I split a path at specific directory?

Tags: c#, string, path

I have the following path...

'X:\Projects\4604-Renovation\Unity\4604_02\Assets\Models\FullBuilding\Materials\'

I want to split it at the directory 'Assets' and end up with...

'Assets\Models\FullBuilding\Materials\'

The directory 'Assets' will not always be in the same place in the path. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `path.IndexOf("Assets")`

Comment: post what have you tried

Comment: Just in case Assets happend to be somewhere before in the path, I'd coded like this `path.toLowerCase().IndexOf("\assets\");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your string is

```
      string completePath = "X:\Projects\4604-Renovation\Unity\4604_02\Assets\Models\FullBuilding\Materials\";
      string subPath = completePath.subString(completePath.IndexOf(@"Assets\"));
```

Please note that if your path contains multiple instances of Assests it will substring from first instance of Asset.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `path.IndexOf`, you can use the `str.SubString(str.IndexOf("\assetse"))`, you can do alot of things. playing with string is kinda fun...

most of the things you want to do with strings you can find on google anyway